# What is the difference between `alloc::rc::Rc` and `std::rc::Rc`?

Tags: module, rust

I'm curious is there a difference between these two modules in practice? And if not, why have these two duplicates then?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463162/use-of-undeclared-type-or-module-corefmtdisplay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::rc::Rc` is just a re-export of `alloc::rc::Rc`. You can see in [src/std/lib.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/std/lib.rs.html#188) that the whole `rc` module is re-exported: `pub use alloc::rc;`

The `alloc` crate is for any kind of memory allocations. Reference counted, Boxed, raw allocations and general access to the underlying allocator (often `jemalloc` in Rust). Since the `Rc` type is such a common type that it should exist in the standard library, but the `alloc` crate should not be a part of the standard library, just the `rc` module of `alloc` is re-exported to the standard library. This saves the user from having to care about the `alloc` crate, and instead offers a clean standard library without odd stuff that is prone to be uncomfortable to use.

Comment: Could you explain why are they re-exported?

Comment: @DanielFath: It's just a matter of flexibility/convenience. On the one hand, it's more flexible to have multiple low-level crates (`core`, `alloc`, `collections`, ...) so that low-level users (such as kernel writers) can cherry pick only the crates that can be used in their context and on the other hand it's more convenient for users to have a single crate to reach for (`std`).